# Qt Creator Align button float to the top

Tags: c++, qt, qgridlayout

I have this gridlayout added onto my centralWidget of my UI in Qt Creator. And I wanted to add several buttons onto the gridlayout. My code is as follows:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton();
    button1->setText("hello");
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(button1, 0,0);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Even though the button is added, it is seen appearing in the middle of the UI when the program is run. And there is a huge gap between the menu bar and button. How do i go about adding the button so that the button will flow nicely below the menu bar?

Please advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid layout was placed in the middle of the UI in design mode, so anything you place inside will fill the fixed rectangle of the grid layout.

To make the grid layout fill the main window, right click the main window and click Lay out > Lay out vertically.

You can also fix the huge gap by placing a vertical spacer below the grid layout.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this method work as well. By setting the alignment for the addWidget portion.

eg:     `ui->gridLayout->addWidget(button1, 0,0, Qt::AlignTop);`